# Tensorflow distribution object returning probabilties greater than 1

Tags: tensorflow

Is there ever any reason a tendsorflow distribution object could return values greater than 1 for probabilities?

This is the basic structure of my code.

NN(input) is a neural network
mu, sigma = NN(inputs)
d = distributions.Normal(mu, sigma)

(Get the probabilities of the targets.)
probs = d.prob(targets)

where mu, sigma and targets are shape [batch_size, 1]

the probs start around 0.5 and as the model trains they gradually increase until they end up as high as 8!

Comment: Could you post or link enough code to reproduce the situation you describe? It'll help a lot.

Comment: It seems you are adding up values when you should be replacing

Comment: Thanks! I edited the original post. I'm not sure it'd be super helpful to include all the details of the network parameterizing the  tensorflow distribution object. But should the .prob method EVER output a number more than 1?

Comment: @SaulloCastro Any chance you could explain that more? Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a bug report. Please file a github issue with steps to repro.